# How to remove an object from a JSON file in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to remove an object from a JSON file using PowerShell.

I read in a JSON file that has some objects in it (C:\eventStaging.json = `[{"server_name":"server1","date":"2021-08-13","user":"user1"},{"server_name":"server2","date":"2021-08-13","user":"user2"}]` )

The plan is to loop through each object, add that object to another json file (`C:\scheduledEvent.json`) and then remove that same object from where it came from (`C:\eventStaging.json`).

Adding each object to a different json file is easy enough. Here is what I have:

```
$json = Get-Content 'C:\eventStaging.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($j in $json){
    $EventStart = Get-Content 'C:\scheduledEventStart.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

    $eventStartList += $EventStart
    $eventStartList += $j
    $eventStartList | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File 'C:\scheduledEventStart.json'
}
```

My problem is removing the object `$j` from `eventStaging.json`.

I have tried:

```
$removeStaging = Get-Content 'C:\eventStaging.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$removeStaging.PSObject.Properties.Remove($j)
$removeStaging | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File 'C:\eventStaging.json' -Force
```

but `$removeStaging` is storing nothing.

I also tried:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$removeStaging = Get-Content 'C:\eventStaging.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$newStaging = $removeStaging.Remove($j)
$newStaging | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File 'C:\eventStaging.json'
```

but again, `$newStaging` stores nothing..

Has anyone any guidance on this please?

Comment: If you're removing _all_ objects from the source file, you may as well delete it - or is there some filtering going on you're not showing? As an aside: `Get-Content -Raw C:\eventStaging.json | ConvertFrom-Json` is much faster.

Comment: `$removeStaging.Remove($j)` should work in principle, but note that it _has no return value_. `.PSObject.Properties.Remove($j)` removes a _property_ from a _single object_, not an _element_ from a _collection_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to PowerShell Core, you can use `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable` when removing the scheduled event from `eventStaging.json` to make this a bit easier:

```
$removeStaging = Get-Content -Raw 'C:\eventStaging.json' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable
$removeStaging.Remove($j)
$removeStaging | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File 'C:\eventStaging.json' -Force
```

---

With Windows PowerShell, your final attempt with the `ArrayList` conversion should have worked, assuming you are trying to remove a top-level element and not a sub-property of the element. Testing with the following code shows my json file is updated with the removed element:

```
# Create test json file
@{Name = 'Bender'; Age = 99}, @{Name = 'Dean'; Age = 98} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File test.json

# Import JSON as ArrayList of PSCustomObjects
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$obj = Get-Content -Raw test.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Remove one of the objects by reference
$obj.Remove($obj[1])

# Write the JSON to file, it will only have the one entry in it
$obj | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File test.json
```

If you update your question with a more complete sample of this area I can evaluate further but either of the above approaches should work.

---

Additionally, note I've removed your use of `Out-String` and instead used `Get-Content -Raw`. The `-Raw` parameter tells `Get-Content` to parse the file as a literal string instead of returning a collection of single-lines.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response and apologies for the late response. $obj.Remove($obj[0]) was what I was missing, it's obvious now.